# 405 method not allowed on delete when api running locally - while published everything works

Tags: c#, .net, api, asp.net-web-api

.Net4.7.2 api.
On Delete controller action i'm getting 405 method not allowed while sending delete request (other requests works fine) from postman or swagger, and when i run api locally by just starting it via visual studio.
When api is published, everything works fine.
What can be the problem?

I don't even know what to search for. In IIS i have got all methods allowed

Additionally: Nothing from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/developer/webapps/iis/health-diagnostic-performance/http-error-405-website works.

Comment: Do any of the "Related questions" help? Depending on which part of the A/B testing you're getting, they will either be below your question or down in the column to the right of the question.

Comment: Yes, tried all of them - including modifications in applicationHost.config, looking on IIS settings if DELETE is not allowed, etc - everything is set how it should be.

Comment: And can you confirm you don't have WebDAV installed? How did you test it when developing, if you can't try the delete method?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.